# Select initial value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 1 column, and these are the values:

```
  Col
   _____
    X
    XA
    XB
    XC
    Yzz
    YZZA
    YZZJ
    YZZR
    ZR
    ZRL
    ZRM
    ZRN
```

How do I do to get only the initial value, the result should be like this:

```
    COL
    ___
    X
    YZZ
    ZR
```

Comment: SUBSTRING/LEFT, SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: Research this problem in individual steps and that should make it more manageable. "SQL Server query first character of string" and "SQL Server query unique values".

Comment: @jarlh can you please take a look to my question i edited it , its not always only 1 char in the left it could be 2 or 3 or 4 , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE Col <> t.Col AND t.Col LIKE Col + '%'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eac66571d8b78d3c845d18e474a1f027).
Results:

```
> | Col |
> | :-- |
> | X   |
> | Yzz |
> | ZR  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the value that has only one character:

```
select t.*
from t
where len(col) = 1;
```

Comment: thank you, but  its not always only 1 char in the left it could be 2 or 3 or 4 .. i edited my question**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're after?

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT Col,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Col,1) ORDER BY LEN(Col) ASC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT Col
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Saves on 2 scans of the table, which (depending on your indexes) could be faster.

Comment: thank you for your response , but it's not always one char in the left , it could be 2 or 3 or 4

Comment: It doesn't make that assumption, @bfs ... It only checks the first character to put into groups, not returns said first character.

Comment: Although this works for the sample data the OP posted, it does not work in a case like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6d645d3d5a0f2e552cb8b8cb611bed5

Comment: Seems to work fine, @forpas, `'X'`,`'YA'`,and `'ZR'` are returned respectively, though I should probably add a further `Col` in the `ORDER BY` clause to maintain reliability.

Comment: No it does not work, because the expected results are: X, YA, Yzzz, ZR.

Comment: @forpas nothing in the OP's questions suggests that. At best, it's an assumption, at worst, the OP's question is incomplete.